# Remove spaces from UPDATE query

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I'm updating a table in postgres database, but i need to remove some spaces between the **":"** string value.

I nedd a string like this:

```
{"value1":"answer1", "value2":"answer2", "nickname":"name1", "color":"red" }
```

But the following code is giving me with some spaces like this:

```
 {"value1":"answer1", "value2":"answer2", "nickname" : "name1", "color" : "red" }
```

Here is my update code:

```
UPDATE t 
    SET    json_col = (Json_build_object ('nickname',nick,'color',color) :: text,'{', '' ) ) :: json;
```

Comment: Whatever is consuming your JSON probably won't care that there is extra whitespace in the JSON content.  The only way I can think to do this would be to use regex.  But using regex against JSON content is very evil, and I can think of many ways that doing so could go wrong here.  So, my answer is that you should not even do anything.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It's an problem because I execute another queries also something like search. I need to remove this extra spaces :/

Comment: Maybe you should be doing this in your app layer, and not in Postgres.

Comment: You might want to consider using `jsonb` type, you'll save space in your database. And you won't have any superfluous spaces.

Answer (score 1):

These whitepaces should not be a problem to you. In [the IEFT JSON specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-1.1),  it is clearly stated that spaces are allowed around structural characters (the  `:`  being one of them) :

> Insignificant whitespace is allowed before or after any of the six structural characters.

```
  ws = *(
         %x20 /              ; Space
          %x09 /              ; Horizontal tab
          %x0A /              ; Line feed or New line
          %x0D )              ; Carriage return
```

In this regard the JSON you exhibited fully conforms to the spec.

There are [functions in Postgres to pretty print JSON](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html) but unfortunately not to tidy it.

It is always possible to manipulate a JSON string with a regular expression but, as commented by @TimBiegeleisen, this is a recipe for disaster... Your best option is to rework the way you consume the JSON (to start with :,why are the spaces a problem ?)